# How to use file_get_contents() with a Wordpress user's cookies

Tags: php, cookies, curl, file-get-contents

I need to send a `file_get_contents()` to an API endpoint with the client's cookies that are set by Wordpress to show that the user is logged into the wordpress site. I know I need to use `stream_context_create()` roughly as follows:

```
$cookies = ??? //THIS IS THE QUESTION (see answer below)!

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: {$cookies}\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://example.dev/api/autho/', false, $context);
```

As you can see from the comment on the first line, I'm stuck on how to send this request so that the correct cookies are sent. I know the correct cookies are sent because I can print out `$_COOKIES` and see them there. But if I try to insert that same array into the headers, it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

ps: I've read that I should use `cURL` for this, but I'm not sure why and I don't know how to use it... but I'm open to the idea.

UPDATE:
I got this to work. It's basically the same thing I was doing, with another important cookie . See my answer below.

Comment: Are you 100% sure there is no client-side (Ajax) way to do this? It would be much cleaner

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Send cookie with file_get_contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431160/php-send-cookie-with-file-get-contents)

Comment: Man, first link after googling `php curl cookies` > http://coderscult.com/php/php-curl/2008/05/20/php-curl-cookies-example/ and full php documentation for [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) especially `CURLOPT_COOKIE`

Comment: @Lusitanian "ps: I've read that I should use cURL for this, but I'm not sure why and I don't know how to use it... but I'm open to the idea." < he should use it :)

Comment: @Vyktor *facepalm* my fault (:

Comment: @Lusitanian: I'll check out the curl resource you recommended, but it not my first choice if this can be done with `file_get_contents()`

@Pekk: There IS a client-side way to do it which works great, but I don't have that option. There's security issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was doing it correctly, but I didn't know that **WP needs a second cookie** sent in order for the request to work properly.

Here's the code that works for me:

```
$cookies = $_COOKIE;
$name;
$value;
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $cookie ) {
    if ( strpos( $key, 'wordpress_logged_in') !== FALSE ) {
        $name = $key;
        $value = $cookie;
    } 
}

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: {$key}={$cookie}; wordpress_test_cookie=WP Cookie check \r\n"
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://mydomain.dev/api/autho/', false, $context);

var_dump($file);
```

It's basically the same thing as you see in my question, but with an important addition: `wordpress_test_cookie=WP Cookie check`. I haven't seen it documented anywhere, but WP needs this cookie as well as the actual wordpress_logged_in cookie in order for the call to happen as an logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

The cookies should be in the following format: `Cookie: cookieone=value; cookietwo=value`, that is, separated by a semicolon and space with no trailing semicolon. Loop through your cookie array, output that format, and send it.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried and it didn't work. I got nothing back from the `file_get_contents`. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as you mentioned you should use [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php) (partially it's my personal opinion, I have some bad experiences with server configuration that prohibited URL file wrappers).

A quote from [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen
>   wrappers have been enabled.

So it may happen to you that the code just won't work. On the other hand `cURL` is designed for fetching of remote content and provides lot of control on what's going on, how to fetch data and so on.

When you look at [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) you can see how many and how detailed things you can set (but you don't have to, it's just optional when you need it).

Here's [the first link](http://coderscult.com/php/php-curl/2008/05/20/php-curl-cookies-example/) after googling [`php curl set cookies`](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php%20curl%20set%20cookies), that's great place for you to start... Basic examples are totally trivial.

Comment: I tried using `curl`, just as shown in that link, but it didn't work. The returned info shows no user logged in. If I enter the API endpoint into the browser, I see the Wordpress user_id, etc. So the cookies are set correctly.

Comment: Do you know if/where I should see that temp file after I test that code? I testing on MAMP PRO and don't see it in Applications/MAMP/tmp/, and I'm wondering if there's a permissions issue or something, but I don't really know what I should expect.

Comment: Update. I found where MAMP stores the file (/private/tmp/COOKIExyz). The file doesn't show the user's logged in status: `mydomain.dev FALSE / FALSE 0 PHPSESSID 8dacd1af06a4cc75936fef743b52a8ef
`

Answer (score 0):

```
$cookies = $_COOKIE;
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $cookie ) {
    if ( strpos( $key, 'wordpress_logged_in') !== FALSE ) {
        $name = $key;
        $value = $cookie;
        break;
    } 
}

// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: {$key}={$cookie}; wordpress_test_cookie=WP Cookie check\r\n"
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://mydomain.dev/api/autho/', false, $context);

var_dump($file);
```

I didn't have points to make a comment, so I readded the code from emersonthis. In order for this to work under my configuration (php 7.0.3, wordpress 4.4.2) I HAD TO remove the last space after the "WP Cookie check" string.