# How to set the cookie for crawler

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In this site, it requires `Yes` click before entering the page.

```
<a id="ok" href="./">Yes</a>
<script>
$('#ok').bind("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var min=60*24*7;
    var dt=new Date();
    dt.setTime(dt.getTime()+(min*60*1000));
    $.cookie('check','1'{domain:'exmaple.com',path:'/',expires:dt});
    window.location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Now I checked the source and understood it needs cookie as `check=1`.

then, I crawl like this in the php script using `file_get_contents`.

```
$url = "https://www.example.com";
$source = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
```

How can I set the cookie ?
or is it possible??

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-a-cookie-with-jquery answer your question?

Comment: This is `javascript`. I want to know how to set the cookie with `php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives me the answer.

[Send cookie with file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431160/send-cookie-with-file-get-contents)

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
```